# Need help to understand AMS DRM management

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, azure-media-services, drm

I am new to mobile programming, and I am making an application which will play video files. I am trying Azure media service (AMS) with Xamarin Forms. I would like to know how to it works to have a file that will play with Widevine on android and Fairplay on IOS.

I need explanations!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

The implementation on the client side for those different DRM's is about as different as you can imagine. Xamarin.Forms does not out of the box provide a component that can handle the DRM specific methods. You will likely need to create platform specific plugins for that or find a ready-made component for that - although in my search i haven't found that. The closest is a cross platform video player such as https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer

Also, you are not likely to get a file to play, it will likely be a stream with different manifests for the two platforms. Azure Media Services however can do that on the fly from a set of MP4's. So it might look like MP4's but what is actually served to the client is a video manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

There is no library/component in Xamarin that allows you to handle multiple DRM schemes. 
Your best option is to use platform libraries wrapped, to be able to consume DRM content. 
I would check out the **Inside Secure** DRM solution, that allows the playback of the DRM Schemes that you listed.

Comment: There is no reason to go with Inside Secure, Azure Media Services already cover the use-case fine.

Comment: @colde I never said that AMS does not provide the DRM functionalities, it's just another option